# MySQL where left join is the highest

Tags: mysql

I want to select the sum of piece for a specific case sharing the same job.
But I only want the result for the highest job.

I have the following table (3dprint)

```
+------+---------+-----------+--------+
| p_id | case_id | Qty_piece | job_id |
+------+---------+-----------+--------+
|    1 |     186 |         1 |      5 |
|    2 |     186 |         2 |      5 |
|    3 |     186 |         4 |      7 |
+------+---------+-----------+--------+
```

So I tried

```
SELECT SUM(Qty_piece) FROM 3dprint
WHERE 3dprint_caseID = 186 
ORDER BY 3dprint_jobID DESC LIMIT 1
```

But it give me 7. I want the 4. How to proceed to get this working ?

Comment: What do you mean by *sum of piece for a specific case sharing the same job* ? Should the sum be max or min of the `qty_piece`? Or do you just need the sum of `qty_piece` for all the `job_ids`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While @P. Jairaj 's answer is correct, there's no need for grouping if you actually will always send the case_id. Use a simpler query as follows.

```
SELECT Qty_piece FROM 3dprint
WHERE case_id = 186  and job_id in (select max(job_id) from 3dprint where case_id = 186)
```

and using your query with small typo fixes and removing the sum function as it irrelevant:

```
SELECT Qty_piece FROM 3dprint
WHERE case_id = 186 
ORDER BY job_id DESC LIMIT 1
```

You're already ordering by job_id and limiting to 1, so no need for the sum function. Only use the sum function when you want to add all values together (totaling)

Comment: I just added `SELECT SUM(Qty_piece)` for having the result directly.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT SUM(Qty_piece) FROM 3dprint
WHERE 3dprint_caseID = 186 
Group by 3dprint_caseID
Having job_id = max(job_id)
ORDER BY 3dprint_jobID DESC LIMIT 1
```